# Group by customer name

Tags: sql-server

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d8bc/5)

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Visit_Date DESC,P_Master.P_Name ASC) AS RowNumber, 
P_Master.P_Name,
(SELECT MAX(Visit_Date) FROM P_Visit v WHERE v.PID = p_Master.PID) as Visit_Date
FROM P_Master
LEFT JOIN P_VISIT
ON P_Master.PID=P_VISIT.PID
WHERE P_Master.P_Name LIKE 'j%'
```

I have to show max date of column Visit_Date if i search on '2013-10-29' then record shows those customers have date '2013-10-29' in coloumn i have to shown max date of customer
all its working fine but How to make group by PID(I have to show only one record for the given search )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below query, it will also help in pagination

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Visit_Date DESC,P_Name ASC) AS RowNumber, * 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT P_Master.P_Name,
(SELECT MAX(Visit_Date) FROM P_Visit v WHERE v.PID = p_Master.PID) as Visit_Date
FROM P_Master
LEFT JOIN P_VISIT
ON P_Master.PID=P_VISIT.PID
WHERE P_Master.P_Name LIKE 'j%') tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
  P_Master.P_Name,
  (SELECT MAX(Visit_Date) FROM P_Visit v WHERE v.PID = p_Master.PID) as Visit_Date
  FROM P_Master
  LEFT JOIN P_VISIT
  ON P_Master.PID=P_VISIT.PID
  WHERE P_Master.P_Name LIKE 'j%'
```

Comment: I have to get rownumber also

Comment: This is what makes the records duplicated though. You can't have one value and rownumber.

Comment: Need to SELECT DISTINCT and add ROW_NUMBER

Comment: ROW_NUMBER gives values 1 and 2, you cannot use distinct for that. What do you need it for?

Comment: But you have other data duplicated this way. And you will have one record only per row number.

Comment: So what is the solution Szymon..I have to get distinct row number what about DENSE_RANK():